# Add vanishing default text Your Name to text input box

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Hi trying to add default vanishing text Your Name that vanishes when person starts to input name to this line of code.

```html
<?php echo '<input type="text" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="30" />';?>
```

Comment: The default text is called the [placeholder attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<input>` tag's `placeholder` attribute like below, if i am not wrong

```
<?php echo '<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="30" />';?>
```

Simple Demo Below

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="" size="30" />
```

## `Update`

You have a Theme installed which use following css in the file `wp-content/themes/realtor/style.css` Line No `5829`

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #fff;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Either you have to modify these in the file or better to override these classes like below, i used `inherit` value you can change to the desired color you want

```
 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: inherit !important;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    color: inherit !important;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, I thought so also earlier and tried it then but didn't work, just tried it again under your recomendation thinking the first time I missed something but again no go. I still have it implemented go down the page to the contact form and check it out http://teamambrose.realtor/property/mls-t3110937-9313-mandrake-ct-tampa-fl-33647/

Comment: Muhammad Thank You! So Much! that was it.

Comment: @Joe no problem mate

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your placeholder is being set to white, so you need to set it to a darker color, for example:

```
input::placeholder {
    color: #bbb;
}
```

Will give you a result like the following:

[image: screenshot of dev tools]

Comment: Hi Xhynk, Thank you, you and Muhammad got it correct and feeling stupid I missed it.